# Is there any way to add and get equipments in a meeting room using Microsoft APIs?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft APIs. I have created equipments, rooms and room-list but I'm not able to add/connect equipments to rooms. I also could not find any sufficient documentation regarding this.

Is there any way to add and get equipments in a meeting room using Microsoft API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to add equipment or create room resources through Microsoft Graph API or Azure AD Graph API. I recommend that you visit [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and add this as a suggestion. (I'm also linking [Azure's User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).)

Currently you can only create Room and Equipment Resources via the [Office 365 Admin Portal](https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/ResourceMailbox) or the [Exchange Admin Center](https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/?rfr=Admin_o365&exsvurl=1&mkt=en-US&Realm=officedev.ninja&RpsCsrfState=b993598e-e7bf-a52a-0668-5e172aa0fde5&wa=wsignin1.0).